# How to make Windows Live Messenger changes my status to Away when running a full-screen program?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-live-messenger, fullscreen

I've found a setting to do the following:

> Show me as "Busy" and block my alerts
>   when I'm running a full-screen program
>   or presentation settings are turned on

I want exactly the same feature, but I want to be shown as "Away", rather than "Busy". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Click on Tools / Options / Personal.  full-screen program or presentation settings are turned
>   on.

then

change status

> Your status is set to busy when your screen saver starts or when the time you set on the Personal tab of the Options dialog box has elapsed.

You cant set as away in full screen

Comment: I can't find the setting you mentioned "Your status is set to Away when your screen saver starts or ...", even though I'm running presentation mode and the full-screen program. Thanks.

Comment: which version live messenger you are using   ?

Comment: Version 2009 (Build 14.0.8089.726)

Comment: Sorry it my mistake . you can set as busy .Not Away